# How to detect Acrobat X Pro installed on machine using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, acrobat

How can I detect if Acrobat X Pro is installed on a machine using javascript. I have code that works for Adobe Reader. but now I have upgrdaed my adobe version to Acrobat X Pro. But it is not working for Acrobat X Pro using IE8.

```
var perform_acrobat_detection = function()
    { 
        //
        // The returned object
        // 
        var browser_info = {
    name: null,
          acrobat : null,
          acrobat_ver : null
        };

        if(navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("chrome") > -1)
            browser_info.name = "chrome";
        else if(navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("msie") > -1)
            browser_info.name = "ie";
        else if(navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("firefox") > -1)
            browser_info.name = "firefox";
        else if(navigator && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()).indexOf("msie") > -1)
            browser_info.name = "other";


        try {
            if(browser_info.name == "ie") {          
                var control = null;
                //
                // load the activeX control
                //                
                try {
                    // AcroPDF.PDF is used by version 7 and later
                    control = new ActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF');
                }
                catch (e){}

                if (!control) {
                    try {
                        // PDF.PdfCtrl is used by version 6 and earlier
                        control = new ActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                }

                if(!control) {     
                    browser_info.acrobat == null;
                    return browser_info;  
                }

                version = control.GetVersions().split(',');
                version = version[0].split('=');

            browser_info.acrobat = "installed";
            browser_info.acrobat_ver = parseFloat(version[1]);
        }
        else if(browser_info.name == "chrome") {
            for(key in navigator.plugins)
            {
                if(navigator.plugins[key].name == "Chrome PDF Viewer" || navigator.plugins[key].name == "Adobe Acrobat") {
                    browser_info.acrobat = "installed";
                    browser_info.acrobat_ver = parseInt(navigator.plugins[key].version) || "Chome PDF  Viewer";
                }
            } 
        }
        //
        // NS3+, Opera3+, IE5+ Mac, Safari (support plugin array):  check for Acrobat plugin in  plugin array
        //    
        else if(navigator.plugins != null)
        {      
            var acrobat = navigator.plugins['Adobe Acrobat'];
            if(acrobat == null)
            {           
                browser_info.acrobat = null;
                return browser_info;
            }
            browser_info.acrobat = "installed";
            browser_info.acrobat_ver = parseInt(acrobat.version[0]);                   
        }


    }
    catch(e)
    {
        browser_info.acrobat_ver = null;
    }

    return browser_info;
};
var browser_info = perform_acrobat_detection();
```

Comment: Can you post your code for detecting Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Jonatan I have edited question with existing code. Appreciate your help in this.

Comment: I've Googled some, and as you probably noticed yourself, Adobe changed the way the version of the software is reported. I hoped there would be an easy version check to alter in your code, but this does not appear to be the case. I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Yes Jonatan, I too googled it, but didnt find any solution. So asked in this forum. Thanks for your time. I am hoping someone might have solution for this issue.

Comment: If no solution is available through Googling, it's unfortunately very likely there *is* no solution